# Optimization function gives incorrect results for 2 similar data sets

Tags: r

I have 2 datasets not very different to each other. Each dataset has 27 rows of actual and forecast values. When tested against Solver in Excel for minimization of the absolute error (abs(actual - par * forecast) they both give nearly equal values for the parameter 'par'. However, when each of these data sets are passed on to the same optimization function that I have written, it only works for one of them. For the other data set, the objective always gets evaluated to zero (0) with'par' assisgned the upper bound value.

This is definitely incorrect. What I am not able to understand is why is R doing so?

Here are the 2 data sets :-

```
test
dateperiod,usage,fittedlevelusage
2019-04-13,16187.24,17257.02
2019-04-14,16410.18,17347.49
2019-04-15,18453.52,17246.88
2019-04-16,18113.1,17929.24
2019-04-17,17712.54,17476.67
2019-04-18,15098.13,17266.89
2019-04-19,13026.76,15298.11
2019-04-20,13689.49,13728.9
2019-04-21,11907.81,14122.88
2019-04-22,13078.29,13291.25
2019-04-23,15823.23,14465.34
2019-04-24,14602.43,15690.12
2019-04-25,12628.7,13806.44
2019-04-26,15064.37,12247.59
2019-04-27,17163.32,16335.43
2019-04-28,17277.18,16967.72
2019-04-29,20093.13,17418.99
2019-04-30,18820.68,18978.9
2019-05-01,18799.63,17610.66
2019-05-02,17783.24,17000.12
2019-05-03,17965.56,17818.84
2019-05-04,16891.25,18002.03
2019-05-05,18665.49,18298.02
2019-05-06,21043.86,19157.41
2019-05-07,22188.93,21092.36
2019-05-08,22358.08,21232.56
2019-05-09,22797.46,22229.69

Optimization result from R
$minimum
[1] 1.018188

$objective
[1] 28031.49



test1
dateperiod,Usage,fittedlevelusage
2019-04-13,16187.24,17248.29
2019-04-14,16410.18,17337.86
2019-04-15,18453.52,17196.25
2019-04-16,18113.10,17896.74
2019-04-17,17712.54,17464.45
2019-04-18,15098.13,17285.82
2019-04-19,13026.76,15277.10
2019-04-20,13689.49,13733.90
2019-04-21,11907.81,14152.27
2019-04-22,13078.29,13337.53
2019-04-23,15823.23,14512.41
2019-04-24,14602.43,15688.68
2019-04-25,12628.70,13808.58
2019-04-26,15064.37,12244.91
2019-04-27,17163.32,16304.28
2019-04-28,17277.18,16956.91
2019-04-29,20093.13,17441.80
2019-04-30,18820.68,18928.29
2019-05-01,18794.10,17573.40
2019-05-02,17779.00,16969.20
2019-05-03,17960.16,17764.47
2019-05-04,16884.77,17952.23
2019-05-05,18658.16,18313.66
2019-05-06,21036.49,19149.12
2019-05-07,22182.11,21103.37
2019-05-08,22335.57,21196.23
2019-05-09,22797.46,22180.51

Optimization result from R
$minimum
[1] 1.499934

$objective
[1] 0
```

The optimization function used is shown below :-

```
optfn <- function(x)
{act <- x$usage
fcst <- x$fittedlevelusage
fn <- function(par)
{sum(abs(act - (fcst * par)))
}
adjfac <- optimize(fn, c(0.5, 1.5))
return(adjfac)
}




adjfacresults <- optfn(test)
adjfacresults <- optfn(test1)

Optimization result from R
adjfacresults <- optfn(test)

$minimum
[1] 1.018188
$objective
[1] 28031.49



Optimization result from R
adjfacresults <- optfn(test1)

$minimum [1]
1.499934
$objective
[1] 0
```

Can anyone help to identify why is R not doing the same process over the 2 data sets and outputting the correct results in both the cases.

The corresponding results using Excel Solver for the 2 datasets are as follows :-

```
For 'test' data set
par value = 1.018236659
objective function valule (min) : 28031 

For 'test1' data set
par value = 1.01881062927878
objective function valule (min) : 28010
```

Best regards

Deepak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the second column of `test1` is named `Usage`, not `usage`. Therefore, `act = x$usage` is `NULL`, and the function `fn` returns `sum(abs(NULL - something)) = sum(NULL) = 0`. You have to rename this column to `usage`.

Comment: Thanks Stephane <- That worked. You are life saver. I was wondering about it all of Thursday evening, all of Friday and all of Saturday and couldn't see it. It was staring at me all along and I couldn't see it. Should have taken a break which I didn't. But thanks again!